# Emitted event from child to parent not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<div @ontabselected="sayHelloFromRoot">
    <tabs>
        <tab></tab>
        <tab></tab>
    </tabs>
</div>
```

I am emitting the event `ontabselected` from `Tabs` component like this:

```
this.$emit('ontabselected', tab);
```

The `sayHelloFromRoot` method resides in  the root vue instance, consisting of only one line:

```
sayHelloFromRoot(){
    console.log('hello');
}
```

But as soon as I switch between tab, in vue-devtools I see the event emitted, but in the console I don't see hello printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer

You should listen event on `<tabs>` instead of `<div>`, e.g.:

```
<div>
  <tabs @ontabselected="sayHelloFromRoot">
    <tab></tab>
    <tab></tab>
  </tabs>
</div>
```

---

#### Explanation

It works the same way as any other event listener. Let's check an example:

```
<!-- MyFile.vue -->
<div>
  <button @click="sayHello"/>
</div>
```

In general. the logic logic here is to listen for event on the component or element that emits the event. In this case, when you as a user click on the button, the `click` event is fired on **button** (not on the wrapper div). And you actually listen for that even in upper component (`MyFile.vue`) not inside the `<button>`.

Even if we back to the roots and use just the html it works the similar way:

```
<div>
  <button onclick="console.log('Hello')"/>
</div>
```

You don't know how button fires the event, it's encapsulated inside the button. But you know that it can emit that event, you know the interface and you can listen on it.

**If the event was implemented in the root, it would be hard to know what button.** (thanks @Ferrybig)

#### Links

- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Listening-to-Events
- https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp
- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

Comment: Why should a component listen to an event emitted by itself? Shouldn't the parent element be the recipient of that event?

Comment: @Eisenheim check the updated answer. Let me know if I've explained it enough

Comment: @Eisenheim Because it would be hard to know what button on the page called onclick, if the event was implemented in the root

Comment: @Ferrybig exactly

Comment: Thanks. I get it. It's just that the official documentation made me so convinced that I actually forgot the very basic. They even had a tagline that goes like this: "Props Down, Events Up"

Comment: Can you tell me why does `sayHelloFromRoot` method gets executed only the first time even though the `ontabselected` event is being emitted each time I switch tabs?